# How to add Cloudflare library to codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I came accross [this Cloudflare library](https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflare-php) and want to implement in codigniter.

How to use the this cloudflare library into the source.

This is the halfway code:

```
        require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/Cloudflare/API/');
        $key     = new Cloudflare\API\Auth\APIKey(CLOUDFLARE_API_USER, CLOUDFLARE_API_USER);
        $adapter = new Cloudflare\API\Adapter\Guzzle($key);
        $user    = new Cloudflare\API\Endpoints\User($adapter);
```

**The error message is:**

> Message: require_once(...\application\libraries\Cloudflare\API):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied

2. I have installed composer and add `require_once('vendor/autoload.php');` like the example in [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001661191-Cloudflare-PHP-API-Binding) and have this error message now:

> Message: require_once(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory

Please help. Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with that code?

Comment: The error is permission denied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/Cloudflare/API/');` is a directory.

You need to use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/):

**Install it:**

- `composer require cloudflare/sdk`

Then use composer's autoloader:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$key     = new Cloudflare\API\Auth\APIKey('user@example.com', 'apiKey');
$adapter = new Cloudflare\API\Adapter\Guzzle($key);
$user    = new Cloudflare\API\Endpoints\User($adapter);

echo $user->getUserID();
```